# Database tables exist but MYSQL says they don't

Tags: mysql

When I log into MySQL and SHOW TABLES, I see a list of the tables.  But, when I run a query against any of them, I get the message:

ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'dbname.tablename' doesn't exist

If I run CHECK TABLE on any of them, I get:

```
+------------------+-------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table            | Op    | Msg_type | Msg_text                                                            |
+------------------+-------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| dbname.tablename | check | Warning  | InnoDB: Tablespace is missing for table 'dbname/tablename' |
| dbname.tablename | check | Error    | Table 'dbname.tablename' doesn't exist                     |
| dbname.tablename | check | status   | Operation failed                                                    |
+------------------+-------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

In my /usr/local/mysql/data directory, I can see my database directory contains both from and `.ibd` files for each of my tables.  From their sizes, it looks like they contain plenty of data.

Please forgive me for asking a question that has been asked before.  I have looked around and seen similar problems related to moving or deleting files.  I have done neither.  The only thing I can think of that has happened is a power off restart without a clean shutdown of anything.

I'm running MYSQL community server 5.6.17 on Mac OS X 10.8.5.

Coincidentally, I have noticed one strange thing: My OS X terminal displays unknowne4ce8f1e830c as my host name where it once showed my computer's name.  I wonder if some path is messed up somewhere.  But, that's just noob speculation and I am in infrequent user of Terminal.  So, they could easily be separate issues.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you really use 'dbname' as your db name and 'tablename' as your table name? My first thought is a syntax error, can you post your query?

Comment: Noob I may be.  But, not that nooby.  No. For the post, I just substituted the generic names for the db and the table.  The actual reference is to lauriejobhistory.jobs (or any table in the lauriejobhistory db).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem.  I'm not completely sure of the cause.  But, it has definitely gone away.

The hostname thing was a red herring.  It changed once I moved onto another network.   It appeared that my attempts to stop and start mysql were not working.  I realized that after getting:

2014-06-18 12:17:39 39973 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete

and checking ps aux | grep mysql

it wasn't shutting down.  Once I successfully restarted, the problem went away.  I'm not sure what caused it originally.  But, it's not an issue now.

Sorry for the distraction.